# Get latest cumulative sales amount for various evaluation dates in SAS

Tags: sql, sas

I have a list of evaluation dates stored in a table, **datelist**.  It's technically two columns, **start_date** and **end_date**, for each evaluation period.  The end_date will definitely need to be used, but the start_date may not.  I only care about periods that are completed, so, for example, the period from 2016-01-01 to 2016-07-01 is in progress but not complete.  So, it's not in the table.

```
start_date  end_date
2012-01-01  2012-07-01
2012-07-01  2013-01-01
2013-01-01  2013-07-01
2013-07-01  2014-01-01
2014-01-01  2014-07-01
2014-07-01  2015-01-01
2015-01-01  2015-07-01
2015-07-01  2016-01-01
```

I have a separate table that lists cumulative sales by customer, **sales_table** with three columns, **customer_ID**, **cumul_sales**, **transaction_date**.  For example, let's say customer 4793 bought $100 worth of stuff on 2/14/2014 and $200 worth of stuff on 3/30/2014 and $75 on 7/27/2014, the table will have the following rows:

```
customer_ID   cumul_sales   transaction_date
4793          100           2014-02-14
4793          300           2014-03-30
4793          375           2014-07-27
```

Now, for each evaluation date and for each customer, I want to know what's the cumulative sales as of the evaluation date for that customer?  If a customer hadn't purchased anything by an evaluation date, then I wouldn't want a row for that customer at all corresponding to said evaluation date.  This would be stored in a new table, called **sales_by_eval**, with columns **customer_ID**, **cumul_sales**, **eval_date**.  For the example customer above, I'd have the following rows:

```
customer_ID   cumul_sales   eval_date
4793          300           2014-07-01
4793          375           2015-01-01
4793          375           2015-07-01
4793          375           2016-01-01
```

I can do this, but I'm looking to do it in an efficient way so I don't have to read through the data once for each evaluation date.  If there are a lot of rows in the sales_table and 40 evaluation dates, that would be a large waste to read through the data 40 times, once for each evaluation date.  Would it be possible with only one read through the data, for example?

The basic idea of the current process is a macro loop that loops once per evaluation period.  Each loop has a data step that creates a new table (one table per loop) to check each transaction to see if it has occurred before or on the end_date of that corresponding evaluation period.  That is, each table has all the transactions that occur before or on that evaluation date but none of the ones that occur after.  Then, a later data step uses "last." to get only the last transaction for each customer before that evaluation date.  And, finally, all the various tables created are put back together in another data step where they are all listed in the SET statement.

This is in SAS, so anything SAS can do, including SQL and macros, is fine with me.

Comment: Can you visualize a dataset for us? It will be easier to help you out that way.

Comment: Please post your current code, so we don't suggest something you're already doing and to provide a starting point.

Comment: Is your sales table missing a sales date?

Comment: I made everything clearer, I hope, including example tables and a basic description of the current process.

Comment: As an alternative to the current method, I could do an INNER JOIN of the two tables on transaction_date <= end_date.  The issue is it would create a lot of rows I don't want as it's a many-to-many join.  It would be great if I could pair this with ordered analytical functions (max over partition by, etc.) to only keep the latest transaction before each evaluation date, but it appears those are not supported in SAS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SAS, when you use group by statement, you can still use not grouping variables in select statement, like this:

```
proc sql;
    create table sales_by_eval as
        select s.customer_ID, s.cumul_sales, d.end_date as eval_date
            from datelist d 
                join sales_table s
                    on d.end_date > s.transaction_date
            group by s.customer_ID, d.end_date
                having max(s.transaction_date) = s.transaction_date
    ;
quit;
```

This mean that for each combination of selected variablem SAS will return rekord with measures summarized within defined group. To limit the result to the last state of transaction value, use having condition, where you select only those records that have transaction_date equal to max(transaction_date) within s.customer_ID, d.end_date group.

Comment: This appears to do exactly what I need.  Thanks so much.  I am thinking I probably learned this about SAS at one point, but I know for sure I forgot it until now.